# Reading .txt in matlab cause closing the software

Tags: matlab

I want to read [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sptXrmQEcHT1RqbHlPX2V2dk0/view?usp=sharing) txt file by Matlab. It is 19 MB. When I run

```
filename = 'clus.txt';
[clussiz,delimiterOut]=importdata(filename);
```

After a while, Matlab is closed. And there is a message in terminal:
killed.

I think it is because `.txt` file is so heavy. What should I do to read and use the information of data?

This is diffrent fro the question of how to read file in Matlab because in this case, I want to read a heavy data.

Comment: What data does your text file have? What is it's size? Either you have to proved the text file or show the snippet/ format of your text file.

Comment: As I said, 19 Megabytes. @SivaSrinivasKolukula

Comment: Where can I upload 19 Megabytes?  @m7913d

Comment: I have seen people uploading in google drive also..

Comment: How can I give you the link of google drive?! @SivaSrinivasKolukula

Comment: Copy the link here....

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sptXrmQEcHT1RqbHlPX2V2dk0/view?usp=sharing @SivaSrinivasKolukula

Comment: @m7913d I added the link

Comment: directly use: data = load('yor text file') ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = load('clus_size.txt') ;
```

Should work..

Also:

```
data = csvread('clus_size.txt') ;
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain the difference with `importdata`.